# Uncaught reference error: document is not defined -- in Javascript (Chrome console)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have code in JavaScript which I execute in a Chrome Browser (in the console DevTool) and it starts with this line:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('names')
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM425:3
InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM37:878
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM37:811
InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM37:667
```

The thing is that the code works just fine sometimes, but most of the times it doesn't! I have read a lot of similar problems in Google and SO threads, but I haven't found a solution.

I tried using `window.onload` but then I got `window is not defined`. I'd like to add that I tried running the script after the webpage was fully loaded (so I guess page loading wasn't the problem).

Comment: What is the execution environment here?  I see `InjectedScript....` which makes me think this isn't a normal browser.

Comment: i'm running it in Google chrome latest update, so it is normal

Comment: It may be the global namespace being polluted, i.e., somewhere else in the global scope `document` is being set.

Comment: Maybe this is a browser plugin that executes before the actual window and document is even initialized?

Comment: @smaili no i'm afraid it's not that

Comment: So you've opened your console (F12) in Chrome, and typed this in, and it returns what you've posted? Unfortunately I don't think anyone will be able to reproduce that issue ?

Comment: @AndreyBorisko i said before that i executed the code after the window was fully-loaded(initialized), so i guess it's not that as well

Comment: @Er.V just a guess...

Comment: @adeneo i didn't post anything, i am using document.getElementsByClassName to identify(get) the elements that are needed for the rest of the code :)

Comment: @Er.V maybe you can reproduce this in jsfiddle or something and share it?

Comment: You're the one that wrote *"I execute in a Chrome Browser (in the console DevTool)"*, I assumed you were actually executing this in the console, as you said ?

Comment: there isn't much to share in jsfiddle, really

Comment: @adeneo no sure i posted that in the console, when you said "it returns what you've posted" i thought you were talking about modifications i did to the website

Comment: All the `InjectedScript` stuff is at least the stack trace, if you type `throw new Error('test')` in the console, you get an error object you can expand to show the same thing etc. so it's just a normal error telling you that `document` is not defined for some reason, why is (almost) impossible for us to tell without knowing the context.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try to restart chrome.